# On Amazon Instance Libreoffice PDF conversion command not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, libreoffice, openoffice.org

Libreoffice PDF conversion command not working on Amazon instance.

I have got the below mentioned scenario. When I am executing same command through root user then its executing on command line but when I am executing same command as Apache user its giving error!!

Executing command with Root user.

```
/opt/libreoffice/program/soffice --headless --nologo --nofirststartwizard --norestore --convert-to pdf:writer_web_pdf_Export --outdir '/var/www/html/con/var/tmp' '/var/www/html/con/var/tmp/imagick-tmp-5e3a4b08d044d.xls'
```

Msg after execution above command with root user

```
/opt/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /opt/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so)
  convert /var/www/html/con/var/tmp/imagick-tmp-5e3a4b08d044d.xls -> /var/www/html/con/var/tmp/imagick-tmp-5e3a4b08d044d.pdf using filter : writer_web_pdf_Export
```

Executing command with Apache user.

```
-uapache /opt/libreoffice/program/soffice --headless --nologo --nofirststartwizard --norestore --convert-to pdf:writer_web_pdf_Export --outdir '/var/www/html/con/var/tmp' '/var/www/html/con/var/tmp/imagick-tmp-5e3a4b08d044d.xls'
```

Msg after execution above command with Apache user.

```
javaldx failed!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
/opt/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information     available (required by /opt/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so)
LibreOffice 6.2 - Fatal Error: The application cannot be started.
User installation could not be completed.
```

I have checked all the installation and permission related things. Everything is fine.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have got the solution, mentioned below.

**Actual Command :-**

```
export HOME=/var/www && /usr/bin/soffice --headless --nologo --nofirststartwizard --norestore  --convert-to pdf:writer_web_pdf_Export  --outdir '/var/www/html/pimcore_root/var/tmp' '/var/www/html/pimcore_root/web/var/assets/demo.xls'
```

**Modified Command :-**

```
export HOME=/var/www && /usr/bin/soffice --headless --nologo --nofirststartwizard --norestore  -env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/LibreOffice_Conversion_${USER} --convert-to pdf:writer_web_pdf_Export  --outdir '/var/www/html/pimcore_root/var/tmp' '/var/www/html/pimcore_root/web/var/assets/demo.xls'
```

**In modified command we have added**
" -env:UserInstallation=file:///tmpLibreOffice_Conversion_${USER} "

and after that everything is working fine.

Comment: Hi, I trying to do something similar, but still no working, i using this `/opt/libreoffice7.2/program/soffice.bin --headless --convert-to pdf my_file.xlsm` any idea why does not work?